# package "arydshln" conflicts with "tabular*"

Tags: tables, arydshln

I am using the following latex code and it is working fine:

```
{
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\par}
```

It shows something like this:

[image: table* example]

However, when I am using the package `arydshln` and my code is like this:

```
\usepackage{arydshln}

{
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\par}
```

the `tabular` goes wrong and it shows something like this:

[image]

I want to know what is going on and how to solve it. Thanks.

I am curious about what happens to cause this problem?

Comment: No idea, but I can recommend the package nicematrix for most cases. Have a look at the manual (`texdoc nicematrix`) on p. 13, command `\diagbox`.

Comment: Curious bug. Use `{|\@\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}l|c|r|}`. But this is academic, because vertical rules in tables should be avoided. Particularly with `tabular*` where they don't really mix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For information, if you use the environment `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix` (which has by default the same syntax as `{tabular*}`), you have directly the expected output, even when `arydshln` is loaded. There is an explanation: with `nicematrix`, the vertical rules are not drawn by the standard mechanism of `tabular` but with PGF/TikZ after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular*}
\par}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

By the way, `nicematrix` provides tools to draw dashed rules (and others) independently of `arydshln`...

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I am curious about what happens to cause the conflicts between ```arydshln``` and ```tabular```.

Comment: In `{tabular}`, a vertical rule is drawn by concatenation of segments (one segment for each row of the tabular) since the tabular is constructed row by row by TeX. If you want a beautiful dashed rule throughout the whole tabular, we can't use that technic. That's why `arydshln` has to do very tricky operations. Hence, it's not surprising to have an incompatibility with `{tabular*}`. With `nicematrix`, the rules are drawn after the construction of the array by using TikZ: it's easier.